# How to set a column as an index in R?

Tags: r, indexing

I want to set a column as an index in R.

```
x<-data.frame(x=c(1,4,5,6,7),y=c(5,7,8,5,9))
x
  x y
1 1 5
2 4 7
3 5 8
4 6 5
5 7 9
```

I want to set x as an index and get the following output:

```
  y
1 5
4 7
5 8
6 5
7 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `column_to_rownames` from `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
x1 <- x %>%
         column_to_rownames('x')
```

---

Or with `deframe`

```
deframe(x) %>% 
        data.frame(y = .)
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
`row.names<-`(x[-1], x$x)
#  y
#1 5
#4 7
#5 8
#6 5
#7 9
```

Comment: but how can i make the values numeric once setting x as an index. Can you please help me with this as well. Thanks @akrun

Comment: @user86907 the `row.names` attribute would be a character class.  You can use `as.integer(row.names(x1))` to convert to numeric.  The reverse option in tidyverse is `rownames_to_column(x1, 'rn') %>% type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`